# ¿Cómo sumar datos de un DataTable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

muchas gracias de antemano, quisiera pedirles un poco de ayuda, estoy trabajando con un DataTable en Laravel, ésta recibe información desde el controlador pero hay una columna de la cuál me gustaría sumar todas las filas de los registros existentes.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@include('egresos.botones')
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Registro de Información
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Responsable</th>
                                <th>Gasto</th>
                                <th>Acción</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($egresos as $egreso)
                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td>{{$egreso->fecha}}</td>
                                <td>{{$egreso->descripcion}}</td>
                                <td>{{$egreso->responsable}}</td>
                                <td>L. {{number_format($egreso->valor, 2)}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    @if(Auth::user()->username == "$egreso->responsable")
                                    <a href="{{url('/egresos', $egreso->id)}}" class="btn btn-success"> Editar &nbsp; <i
                                        class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i> </a>
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Responsable</th>
                                <th>Gasto</th>
                                <th>Acción</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Este es el código de la plantilla que recibe la información. La información me funciona bien, pero, quisiera sumar todas las filas de la columna gasto, es posible? si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Puedes enseñarnos el controlador, o mejor dicho, el método del controlador?

Comment: `public function index()
    {
        $egresos = Egreso::all();
        return view('egresos.index', compact('egresos'));
    }`

Comment: Esa es la forma en la que paso la información a la vista

Comment: Cuando añadas información, añadela editando la pregunta, es mas legible y estara más a mano para gente que pueda ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

La lógica en MVC se coloca en el controlador (o en el modelo en caso de que este relacionado con el). De esta manera pasamos una variable extra a la vista con el total:

```
public function index() { 

    $egresos = Egreso::all(); 

    $total = number_format(Egreso::sum('valor'), 2);

    return view('egresos.index', ['egresos' => $egresos, 'total' => $total]); 
}
```

Y ya solo te queda colocar ese total de la manera que más te convenga.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la documentación de Laravel [Collections Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sum) existe el método "sum()"

Puedes realizar la suma directamente desde la vista , checalo te lo describo en el código (no coloque todo el código solo para optimizar la respuesta):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@include('egresos.botones')
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

       {{-- code --}}

        <div class="col-md-12">
           {{-- Desde la variable "$egresos" no dentro del foreach se accede al método sum y suma todo los campos llamado "valor" --}}
           <p>El total es : {{ $egresos->sum('valor') }}</p>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```